# Question on job form: "Is your code available on request?"

Tags: applications

I am filling out a programmer job application form online, and one of the questions is: "Is your code available on request?" What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Is that a job application for a programmer job? Code like in source code?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: is your code available to them, should they request it?

For example, I would have to say "No" because all the code I wrote in the last years is the property of the company I wrote it for and they won't give it to somebody else.

If your former company is fine with giving out the code, or it's open or shared source or it belongs to you personally and you are fine with giving it out, check "Yes".

Comment: Its extremely prudent for developers these days to maintain an active Github account with public repositories - not of your employers code, but of your personal projects, forks of open source applications you contribute to etc etc.  Put that on your CV and you won't have issues with these sorts of questions.

Comment: Married software developers have better things to do in their spare time than to run personal projects or contributing to open source applications. Same for software developers with boyfriends  or girlfriends, or single parent software developers. Do you know any plumber who does plumbing at home, or manager who manages things in his spare time, and so on?

Comment: To follow up @gnasher729 in many country's your employer may well own code that you write outside of work unless  its "unrelated"  to your day job.

Comment: Hear about github all the time on here, don't even really know what it is... will Google it one day.

Comment: @gnasher729 Then those software developers will have a hard time getting hired. A worker who doesn't have a passion for doing what he does (and how could you not with all the cool things you can do with code?) isn't one many people jump to hire. And seeing how many devs DO regularly do personal projects, you're not just not standing out from the crowd, the crowd is standing out from you.

Comment: @A.McDaniel Passion has nothing to do with GitHub. Every day has 24h and somebody who puts 8 hours into programming and then *more* hours into programming instead of seeing his wife is on the wrong side of "passion". Only a very few people I know have private projects on GitHub, because most are good enough to actually make money with their coding. And none of them had problems getting hired.

Comment: @nvoigt I can't disagree more. If you're only working 8 hours a day, you're not working enough, and if you're not working on improving your career by learning new technologies, you're falling behind. Your opportunities to ethically learn new technologies (i.e., not on your employers dime) are your own responsibility. These facts are part of the programmer career. If you want to work a 9 to 5 and then check out you won't go far in this career field.

Comment: @A.McDaniel Going to conferences and checking out new technologies building POCs to see if we can use them has *always* been part of my job description over multiple employers and 15+ years. I guess my viewpoint depends a lot on the fact that for me it *is* ethical to do exactly that. I have never seen the need to have private pet projects on the side, when I could get paid doing it in those 8 hours a day.

Comment: @nvoigt I don't know of any employers here that could justify sending employees to conferences to their shareholders. Shareholders would be screaming if we paid for employees to not only lose 5 productive days, but travel, just to explore some personal pet project! The workplace is busy enough at it is doing our regular jobs--we don't have time as it is.

Comment: @A.McDaniel I totally agree with gnasher729. I have way more important and enjoying things to do in my spare time than work on personal coding projects. I haven't written a single line of code at home that wasn't job related or read a single article on my own time in years. I also work a straight 8 hours a day and have been doing that for about 20 years and its never been a problem. If I need to learn a new technology then I do it on the clock. Period. Personal time is too important to me. I'm currently doing microservice dev in Kubernetes and learning as I go so no, my skills are not stale.